# Partial view inside table doesn't get model properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-table, partial

I have a table with partial view inside:

```html
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.Name)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.Partial("_taskDetails", item)
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

My `_taskDetails`, which is partial view, only gets the first instance of model `item`. What am I missing here? Actually, I am using a button in `_taskDetails` which means I have a button in every row of table in `Index.cshtml`. when I push the button in every row, I just get an instance of the first row, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

This is in your view page(Index.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Sample>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.Name)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.Partial("_taskDetails", item)
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

Create a partial view as "_taskDetails.cshtml"
Inside that partial view add the following:

```
@model Models.Sample
 <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Customer.Name)
 </td>
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but It isn't the point. Actually I am using a button in "_taskDetails" which means I have a button in every row of table in "Index.cshtml". when I push the button in every row, I just get instance of first row, and I don't know why?!

Answer (score 0):

Just use

@Html.Partial("_taskDetails", Model)
instead of

@Html.Partial("_taskDetails", item)

Share feedback...